# Automapping Error mapping types after upgrade from 7.0.1 to 11.0.0

Tags: c#, automapper

I have upgraded from Automapper 7.0.1 to 11.0.0 (the dependency injection package).  No changes to the data structures, or mapping code other then to move to the dependency injection model.

I have one mapper that is throwing an error, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  TYIA.

The mapping code:

```
CreateMap<Group, GroupViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.LastUpdateUserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.LastUpdateUser.UserName))
            .ForMember(x => x.GroupId, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Id))
            ;
```

The mapping call:

```
var mGroupVM = _mapper.Map<List<Group>, List<GroupVM>>(mGroup);
```

Group Definition:

```
public class Group : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column("date_created")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

        [Column("last_update")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }

        [Column("last_update_user_id")]
        public string LastUpdateUserId { get; set; }

        [Column("last_update_user")]
        public ApplicationUser LastUpdateUser { get; set; }

        [Column("active")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [Column("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<GroupRole> GroupRoles { get; set; }
        
        public List<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }

        [Column("update_date")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        [Column("updated_by")]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    }
```

GroupVM definition:

```
public class GroupVM
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdateUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser LastUpdateUser { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

The error message:

```
[Error]  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
List`1 -> List`1
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[XXX.Data.Entities.Group, Project Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[XXX.Models.GroupViewModels.GroupVM, ProjectWebApp, Version=0.7.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Group -> GroupVM
XXX.Data.Entities.Group -> XXX.Models.GroupViewModels.GroupVM
   at lambda_method2352(Closure , Group , GroupVM , ResolutionContext )
   at lambda_method2351(Closure , List`1 , List`1 , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method2351(Closure , List`1 , List`1 , ResolutionContext )
```

Comment: `CreateMap<Group, GroupVM>()`

Comment: Well - I feel like an idiot.  Thank Lucian!!  Still not sure why this worked with the old version, and not in the new.....but this fix worked.

Answer (score 1):

CreateMap<Group, GroupVM>() –
Lucian Bargaoanu
Jul 7 at 14:12